Use Realm Swift Query API to query object attributes contained in a List
I'm using Realm in a Swift project to store my data. I want to use the Realm Swift Query API to query object attributes contained in a List.
My (simplified) objects look like:
open class QuestionModel: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var uuid: String!
    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uuid"
    }
    // attributes about the media for this question are wrapped up in a MediaModel object
    @objc dynamic var media: MediaModel?
    
}

open class MediaModel: Object {
    // A question can have up to two ImageModels    
    open var images = List<ImageModel>()

}

open class ImageModel: Object {
    // The filename on disk to use to create a UIImage
    @objc dynamic var filename: String? = nil
    // an description of the image
    @objc dynamic var altDescription: String? = nil
   
}

In some circumstances I want to only get QuestionModels where the first ImageModel.filename != ""
Here's what I've tried:
res = realm?.objects(QuestionModel.self)

and I want to further filter the QuestionModels based on certain criteria
Using NSPredicate and Subquery seems to work, though I don't think it understands which image.name is blank, it just gives me all questions where one of the image.filenames is filled in
res = res.filter("SUBQUERY(media.images, $image, $image.name != '').@count > 0")

However, I really want to move to the new Realm Swift Query API if possible.
res = res.where {
                $0.media.images.name != ""
            }

Gives NSException * "Key paths that include a collection property must use aggregate operations"
res = res.where {
           ($0.media.images.name != "").count > 0
        }

Give NSException *  "Subqueries must contain a keypath starting with a collection."
I'm very confused. I can't seem to find an example online which makes me wonder if this is possible.
Any thought appreciated

Cross post over to the Realm Forums here where there is additional discussion.

There's a typo in your code causing an/the issue $image.name.  The ImageModel model doesn't name a name property - the filter should be filename. Also here ($0.media.images.name != "").count > 0 should be .filename

Yes, sorry. Typo was introduced when trying to simplify the example

I ended up using the NSPredicate SUBQUERY to acheive my aims
